# Support for docker data volume in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

I am wondering if AWS Beanstalk supports docker data volumes or does it only support host volumes? I am reading the beanstalk [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) and I see that `Volumes` in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` is for the EC2 directories (host). I then figured a docker data volume must simply be a separate container for housing data but when I read this in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#choose-the--v-or-mount-flag):

> **Create and manage volumes** 
>   Unlike a bind mount, you can create and
>   manage volumes outside the scope of any container.

To me that indicates that a data volume is NOT a container. With that said, how can I create one using elastic beanstalk if Volumes is for host directories and a docker volume is different than a container? Is this not supported?

Basically I want elastic beanstalk to do this:

```
$ docker volume create --name nexus-data
$ docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
```

using the config:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "someimage:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8081"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "nexus-data": "/nexus-data" <-- This is for host = Wrong!
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

Comment: If you want to persist data in Beanstalk for container you may have to use [S3 or EFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852423/persistent-storage-on-elastic-beanstalk).
Have you looked at Amazon Elastic Container Service to run your container? I feel [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html) is quite explanatory to help you understand how you can use volumes for different use-cases. It even allows you to use volumes from another container (the quite old way used to persist data).

Comment: Thanks @MiguelA.C., I am starting to realize S3 is the way to go. I'll just have to use some plugin. I do have to stick with elastic beanstalk because of orginaztional reqs but I'll look into it.

Comment: Why do you need docker volume? What are are trying to solve?

Comment: If you are insistent on using docker containers, general consensus is to use EC2/ECS on AWS. Elastic Beanstalk effectively mimics containerization for people who don't use Docker yet